# Ansible task based on debug output

Tags: web-services, ansible

I'm using Ansible to run few test cases against our web services. Following is my playbook:

```
    - hosts: localhost
      connection: local
      tasks:
        - name: Testing the API...
          uri:
          url: https://api.example.com/v1/
          method: GET
          user: username
          password: password
          status_code: 200
          return_content: yes
          force_basic_auth: yes
        register: results

       - debug: var=results
```

Above playbook works fine and returns the following output:

```
    ok: [localhost] => {
   "results": {
    "access_control_allow_origin": "*", 
    "cache_control": "max-age=864000, private", 
    "changed": false, 
    "connection": "close", 
    "content": "\r\n{\"id\":1,\"deleted\":false,\"first-name\":\"xxx\",\"last-name\":\"xxx\",\"name\":\"xxx\",\"title\":\"xxx\",\"background\":\"\",\"company-id\":xx,\"company-name\":\"example\",\"company-type-id\":2,\"company-type-name\":\"Customer\",\"email-address-work\":\"kk@example.info\",\"email-address-personal\":\"\",\"email-address-alternate\":\"\",\"email-address-other\":\"\",\"phone-number-work\":\1234567890\",\"phone-number-home\":\"\",\"phone-number-mobile\":\"252654789\",\"phone-number-alternate\":\"256471235\",\"business-street\":\"526574, usa\",\"business-city\":\"San Antonio\",\"business-state\":\"TX\",\"business-zip\":\"1234607\",\"business-country\":\"United States\",\"home-street\":\"\",\"home-city\":\"\",\"home-state\":\"\",\"home-zip\":\"\",\"home-country\":\"\",\"created-time\":\"2015-11-03T20:56:33.000Z\",\"last-modified-time\":\"2017-11-21T06:27:55.000Z\",\"tags\":[]}", 
    "content_length": "857", 
    "content_type": "application/json", 
    "date": "Tue, 21 Nov 2017 09:59:34 GMT", 
    "expires": "Fri, 01 Dec 2017 09:59:34 GMT",
```

Now, I want to run another task if there is any data outside the flower brackets of the 'content' section. In the above output, it starts with `'content": "\r\n{\"id\":1,\"deleted...'`. Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: So you ask how to write a condition that evaluates to `true` if the first character is not `{`?

Comment: yes, you are correct

Comment: Are you sure this is what you need?

Comment: Yes, this play is used for testing the API after deploying the new code. So usually developers place the debug code outside the flower brackets. If any such code found outside the flower brackets, they need to be notified. I'll be writing a email notification step if the content area (outside { ) has any characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This condition should suffice:

```
when: "(results.content | regex_replace('{.*}', '')) != ''"
```

Just check if the string is empty after removing everything between `{` and `}`.

Comment: my bad. It works. It was my misunderstanding. I updated my play and able to see the correct results. Can you please help me to ignore '\r\n' outside the { ?